# profile, messages, bookmarks and preferences: foreach activity with excel file and Oracle application

Tags: uipath

i have done an automation with UiPath. the automation takes rows from excel sheet to enter it to the Oracle application. the robot works otherwise fine but in the oracle form when i finish line one it doesn’t move to line two. the robot takes line two in the excel sheet and repeat it in line 1 again and again until all rows are complete.
i have sent a hot key at the end to move to line two at oracle but it comes back to line 1 again. as the Image i don't know what I have to do

image
image
1920×1080 178 KB

i have tried for each row it works with the excel but note oracle GL